# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'AxiosHeaders...' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm working on the authorisation feature of a react app. This is tsx file for making http requests using axios:

```
import React from "react";
import axios, { Method } from "axios";

import { API_BASE_URL } from "../constants/url-constants";

class RequestService {
    get = (url: string, isAuthRequired: boolean = false, contentType: string = "application/json") => {
        return createRequest("GET", url, null, isAuthRequired, contentType);
    };

    post = (url: string, body: any, isAuthRequired: boolean = false, contentType: string = "application/json") => {
        return createRequest("POST", url, body, isAuthRequired, contentType);
    };

    put = (url: string, body: any, isAuthRequired: boolean = false, contentType: string = "application/json") => {
        return createRequest("PUT", url, body, isAuthRequired, contentType);
    };

    delete = (url: string, isAuthRequired: boolean = false, contentType: string = "application/json") => {
        return createRequest("DELETE", url, null, isAuthRequired, contentType);
    };
}

const createRequest = (method: Method, url: string, body: any, isAuthRequired: boolean, contentType: string) => {
    return axios({
        method: method,
        url: API_BASE_URL + url,
        data: body,
        headers: setHeader(isAuthRequired, contentType)
    });
};

const setHeader = (isAuthRequired: boolean, contentType: string) => {
    if (isAuthRequired) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem("token");
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
    }
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = contentType;
};

export default new RequestService();
```

I get this error in the return statement of createRequest:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(config: AxiosRequestConfig<any>): Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'AxiosHeaders | (Partial<RawAxiosHeaders & { Accept: AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Length": AxiosHeaderValue; "User-Agent": AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Encoding": AxiosHeaderValue; Authorization: AxiosHeaderValue; } & { ...; }> & Partial<...>) | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined): Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ method: Method; url: string; data: any; headers: void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(312, 3): The expected type comes from property 'headers' which is declared here on type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'
```

I'm new to typescript/axios and I've no idea about this error.

Comment: don't set the default headers on a per call basis like that - `setHeader` needs to return something...

Comment: @DanielA.White Like how?

Comment: `return { 'Content-Type': ... }`

Comment: @DanielA.White But I need to check for every call whether authorisation is required or not.

Comment: That doesn't matter? The function `setHeader` currently returns nothing. You're using it as if it should. Either make it return something (the more logical usage) or don't (in which case you might need to to change more code).